# cant update json stored in Myjson.com

Tags: android, json

I have stored a json in Myjson.com and I am using it in my android app. now I want to upgrade stored data but I am unable to do that. I've read the example given in http://myjson.com/api  to update Json example is this :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.myjson.com/bins/:id",
    type:"PUT",
    data:'{"key_updated":"value_updated"}',
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

    }
});     `
```

but cant figure it out. my json data is as below:

```
[{"id":"priceup","value":"0"},{"id":"appup","value":"0"},{"id":"nezam","value":"16000"},... ]
```

anybody knows how can I update above data any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new JSON the PUT  method returns in the data the url of the newly created resource. Hence, you need to use this url and not the generic **https://api.myjson.com/bins/:id**.

An example (jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s6b2t8oh/)):

```js
function updateJson(url) {
    var obj = [{"id":"priceup","value":"0"},{"id":"appup","value":"0"},{"id":"nezam","value":"16000"}];
    var data = JSON.stringify(obj);
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:"PUT",
        data: data,
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log(data); // now data contains the updated data
        }
    });
}

//
// create a new JSON....
//
$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.myjson.com/bins",
    type:"POST",
    data:'{"key":"value"}',
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        var url = data.uri; // data contains the url....
        updateJson(url);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your clear answer. just I don't know where should I run mentioned code. can I enter the code in jsfiddle .net and run code.  please show me how to run this code.

Comment: also where have u puted url in your example icant spot the url in code

Comment: @saberjavadi In order to run the code it's enough you click on **here** hyperlink. The url comes from the api create json: **data.uri**. Because this is set in an async callback I used a function callback: **updateJson**

Comment: appreciate for your help. Thank you very much

Comment: sorry there is no clickable link here : "In order to run the code it's enough you click on here hyperlink."